# Redirect users to web address based on database data

Tags: php, url, redirect

I'm using in my add-vehicle.php the following code to redirect my users after submitting a form and it works..(this is not the whole code)

```
if(isset($_GET['success'])  && empty($_GET['success'])) ....(is true)

header('Location: www.mysite.com/add-vehicle?succses');
```

But I want to redirect my users to a unique webadres. For example:

`www.mysite.com/add-vehicle?succses/car_id=1` and the next one to `www.mysite.com/add-vehicle?succses/car_id=2'`

so I want to output the data of my Database in my url..
What is the best way to do it?

Comment: Query the database for the information, and append it to the location string.

Comment: fetch the data from the database, bind it to a variable and put it into your url string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use your `PHP` variable to adjust the URL.

```
header('Location: http://' . $_DBPage);
```